# Error al iniciar un script de Javascript en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, consola

Tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de iniciar un script en el leguaje javascript cuya librería es nodejs.
La versión del node que tengo instalado es v6.11.1 y mi ordenador es un Mac cuyo sistema operativo es MacOS Sierra.
El script que intento iniciar es un simple hola mundo, ya que estoy empezando:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writehead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('hola #backendpro\n');

}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at [http.://127.0.0.1:3000/'][1]);
```

Escribo en la consola cd y arrastro mi carpeta donde tengo el script y seguidamente escribo node y el nombre de mi archivo que deseo correr y la consola me devuelve un Server running at http.://127.0.0.1:3000/

hasta que abro el navegador y en el URL escribo localhost:3000 y me aparece lo siguiente en la consola:

> Mac-mini-de-Ivan:node ivan$ node holanode.js Server running at
>   http.://127.0.0.1:3000/ /Users/ivan/Desktop/node/holanode.js:5
>   res.writehead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
>       ^
>
> TypeError: res.writehead is not a function
>       at Server. (/Users/ivan/Desktop/node/holanode.js:5:5)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23) Mac-mini-de-Ivan:node ivan$ node holanode.js Server running at
>   http://127.0.0.1:3000/ /Users/ivan/Desktop/node/holanode.js:5
>   res.writehead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
>       ^
>
> TypeError: res.writehead is not a function
>       at Server. (/Users/ivan/Desktop/node/holanode.js:5:5)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)

y no se como solucionarlo, he leído muchos artículos pero ninguno me han ayudado del todo. Os estaría muy agradecido a aquel/la que me solucione este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Los metodos son "case sensitive", es decir debes usar las mayusculas en los nombres. En este caso, tienes `res.writehead` pero el nombre del metodo requiere una H mayuscula.

Usa `res.writeHead` en lugar de `res.writehead`.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está bien, pero se puede mejorar un poco más utilizando la nueva sintaxis de ES2015 y separando de forma adecuada el servidor para realizar operaciones sobre el y no encadenarlo todo en una sentencia:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Un detalle a tener en cuenta al declarar el puerto es utilizar las variables de entorno **'env'** de NodeJS, ya que cuando hagas deploy al server, le permitirás elegir el puerto establecido en la variable de entorno y no un puerto específico, porque si no es así, siempre estará escuchando en el puerto 3000 y en algún momento puede que no esté disponible o no es útil para los requerimientos de tu ecosistema. Todo depende del entorno de ejecución del servidor al que hagas deploy.